# Facebook link custom info

Tags: facebook, api

I am not even sure what its called, but when you put a link in Facebook in your comments, an image and a little description come up. I am looking to do this for my website, I just have no idea where to start, can someone shed some light on this.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Your posting from an FB app / FB API?

Comment: I have no idea what its called, I am just looking for way so when a facebook user, uses my link in there comment back a certain image text appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users post your URL in their wall, you can help Facebook choose this for you by putting this in your web page's `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="title" content="Your Title" />
<meta name="description" content="You Description" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

IMB's answer will probably work, but what you really want is [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) metadata in there.

That's the first thing the Facebook parser looks for when scanning pages for descriptions and images.

Once you've added the metadata, you can use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to confirm that everything is as you want. Not only will that tool show you what properties Facebook is detecting, it also has the added benefit of blasting away Facebook's cache for that page, so you can be sure that it's displaying the most up to data information for your site.